# Why does df say my EFS disk has a capacity of 8 Exabytes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, disk-space-utilization, df, amazon-efs

This is a screenshot from my AWS EC2 instance, which the EFS disk is mounted on:

[image]

How can this be?

Comment: That's normal, what specifically are you questioning?

Comment: @kenlukas The disk is literally that big?

Comment: Pretty much, AWS says it's unlimited.  I'm guessing there has to be some top end limit but thousands of petabytes is possible.

Answer (score 3):

EFS claims it can store "petabytes of data", expanding automatically. AWS has likely decided that 8 exabytes is the number they want to present to the operating system as free space. I can't see any advantage to presenting a smaller number, as some software wants to know free space available on a disk.

From the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/faq/)

**Q. How much data can I store?**

Amazon EFS file systems can store petabytes of data. Amazon EFS file systems are elastic, and automatically grow and shrink as you add and remove files. You do not provision file system size up front, and you pay only for what you use.

Comment: That's a good thing since its easy to end up with duplicate data.